# Google Apps script function for changing currency format

Tags: google-apps-script, custom-function

I am inexperienced in js coding and while trying for 4 hours to get into it I am lost. I am trying to create a custom Google spreadsheet function that would change the currency from currently chosen to the Euro in the same cell as the function is written. There is no built-in function that would do that. I am planning to use it in a conjunction with a condition (if true -> then change currency). Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) cannot change the number format of a cell, so your function will have to return a formatted text string rather than a number, like this:

```
/**
* Formats a number as a text string.
*
* See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php.
*
* @param {42.50} number The number to format.
* @param {"€ %01.2f"} format A format template to apply.
* @customfunction
*/
function FormatString(number, format) {
  return Utilities.formatString(format, number);
}
```

If you need to keep the formatted values as numbers, you will need to write a function that uses [Range.setNumberFormat()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat) and call it through some other means, such as a [button](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets), a [custom menu item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus), a [sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars) or a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).